# submit django form on checkbox select

Tags: javascript, django, django-forms, django-views

tml:

```
<div id="report-liveonly">
  <form action="." id="status" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
  <p>{{SearchKeywordForm.status}}Only show LIVE reports</p>
  </form>
</div>
```

I am trying to submit the searchform on checkbox click.It is not working. Onclick also not happening,i checked with alert message.

The total function is to show the live report,if `Only show LIVE reports` checkbox is checked.

Need help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the solution,

```
class SearchKeyword(Form):
    search_keyword = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Keyword Search','class':'keyword-search'}))
    status = forms.BooleanField(widget=forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={'onclick':'this.form.submit();'}),required=False, label="Status")
```

Comment: Also works for django_filters.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter fields ;-) Thx